# 02 Buick Regal - key stuck in ignition when trying to start

Tags: security, ignition-key

Car is a 2002 Buick Regal GS. When I turn the key to the on position, the lights will come on, the gauges will activate, etc. but when I turn the key to start the vehicle, everything shuts off and the key is locked into the ignition.

I have to release the key via the slot beneath the ignition and then short the battery out to reset everything. I cannot get it to start whatsoever.

Comment: What do you mean by "short the battery out"? Your issue is most likely battery related. Clean up the posts and ensure the battery is fully charged, then let us know what happens.

Comment: I usually just tap a socket wrench to the negative post or disconnect the negative post and tap the cable to the terminal. 

The posts are corrosion free and secure to the battery. The battery has sufficient voltage and the CCAs are in the correct range.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you take the key off of the key ring?  if I had to guess, I'm thinking cracked ignition switch housing.

Comment: Could you explain more about this shorting of the battery?  You say you tap the negative post?  Do you mean you literally just hit the negative post with a wrench?

Comment: Yes, I have a spare set of keys and it does the same issue and the spare isn’t on a key ring

Comment: What you're describing is usually a problem with the connection, at either end of either power cable from the battery. Ensure there is fresh, clean metal on all of these surfaces, then reattach the cables. I'm betting if you do all four ends this way, you'll solve your issue.

Comment: I agree with what you’re saying, but the reason I’m posting is because those steps have been followed. Both battery terminals are free of corrosion and tightly secured. I even ran a new additional ground wire to the chassis to make sure.

Comment: Step #1. Where are you going here?  Are you trying to fix this yourself?  Are you trying to understand what to say to your mechanic? etc...Step #2 (DIY route) Do you know how to use a mulitmeter?  (Voltage, Ohms)   Step #3, obtain wiring diagram for your vehicle (even if from the back of Chilton / Haynes manual)... Step #4...

Comment: @Jay - "Fresh metal" and "free of corrosion" are two separate things. Just because there is no white stuff on the terminals doesn't mean it is connecting correctly.

Comment: @Paulster2 both the battery and the terminal posts have been replaced. The positive and negative leads have both been sanded/grinded prior to making sure the physical connections are tight. I’ve explored virtually every battery-related electrical issue that could be causing this.